# How does the google cloud ml engine predict function work?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

How does the google cloud ml engine predict function work? Does it apply the same data transformations on the test data point as it does on the training data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

predict works out of the model exported from training. So, if your model has the transformations built in (for e.g. tf transform), then yes the same transforms will be applied.

Do you have something specific you want to know? I suggest this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/prediction-overview